# Транслітерація слова 'легені'

Tags: transliteration

Яка правильна транслітерація слова 'легені' на англійську мову: 'legeni' чи 'leheni'?

Comment: Питання не демонструє власної спроби відповіді. -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Є різні системи транслітерації (зокрема див. дві таблиці в [розділі «Tables of romanization systems» статті «Romanization of Ukrainian» в англійській вікіпедії](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Ukrainian#Tables_of_romanization_systems)).

Проте більшість сучасних систем, зокрема чинний стандарт, затверджений [постановою Кабінету Міністрів України від 27 січня 2010 р. N 55 «Про впорядкування транслітерації українського алфавіту латиницею»](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/55-2010-%D0%BF/ed20160112), який застосовують зокрема для офіційних документів, імен, географічних назв і було прийнято міжнародно (зокрема [UNGEGN (Групою експертів ООН з географічних назв) 2012](http://www.eki.ee/wgrs/res/res_10_9.htm) і [BGN/PCGN (Радою США з географічних назв та Постійним комітетом з географічних назв для британського офіційного використання) 2019](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/864314/ROMANIZATION_OF_UKRAINIAN.pdf)), кажуть передавати *г* через *h*.